# Sql Server Pivoting

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Trying to convert the row value to column (PIVOT) of the given table.

```
S.No          ID    Column2 Column3
1              1    1       Firstname
2              1    2       MiddleName
3              1    14      ContactNumber
4              2    1       Firstname
5              2    14      ContactNumber
6              3    14      ContactNumber
7              3    2       MiddleName
```

I want like below for ID 1

```
Column2 1           2           14
Column3 FirstName   MiddleName  LastName
```

please help me to solve it.
Thanks

Comment: Why does output show LastName under 14 instead of ContactNumber? There is no LastName in source data.

Comment: If this is a mssql, you could use PIVOT (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15). If you'd some problems with that, please provide minimal reproducible example (https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then we can discuss that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like should be a simple CROSSTAB (PIVOT) query, like (syntax from Access database query builder):

```
TRANSFORM First(Table2.Col3) AS FirstOfCol3 
SELECT Table2.ID 
FROM Table2 
GROUP BY Table2.ID PIVOT Table2.Col2;
```